# The verbs which might be used with both "avere" and "essere"

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verb

Although I didn't encounter a general rule to choose the correct auxiliary verb whether being *`avere`* or *`essere`* along with the verbs to use, would like to know if there are, even little tricks to determine.

While this occurs, recently, witnessed a versatile type of usage from a native Italian speaker who said **`sei atterrato`** rather than **`hai atterrato`**, *which is documented as the right style whenever I searched for*, to the interlocutor one.

Can you please explain me that if such a usage is true, and is there some other verbs which might be used along with both of the auxiliary verbs, and in which situations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se è riferita ad esempio ad atterrare con un aereo, cioè è usato come verbo intransitivo, le forme 'sei atterrato' o 'hai atterrato' sono entrambe grammaticalmente corrette, anche se la forma 'hai atterrato' a me sembra inconsueta.

Ma 'atterrare' ha anche il significato, come verbo transitivo, di 'buttare giù', ad esempio 'ha atterrato con un pugno l'avversario'.

La scelta dell’ausiliare essere o avere può cambiare a seconda che questo verbo sia usato in forma transitiva o intransitiva.

Un caso in cui viene usato sia l'ausiliare 'essere' che l'ausiliare 'avere', è quello del verbo 'volare', sempre intransitivo, ma che prevede  'essere' o 'avere' a seconda delle situazioni.
La seguente citazione è dal dizionario Sapere.it di De Agostini:

> Nei tempi composti il verbo intransitivo volare prevede l’uso
> dell’ausiliare essere o di avere, in casi diversi. L’ausiliare è avere
> quando il volo è inteso come un’azione continuata (il gabbiano ha
> volato per due giorni prima di guadagnare la costa; non ho mai volato
> in aereo); è essere quando è inteso come un’azione breve e immediata
> (l’uccellino è volato via); inoltre è sempre essere nei significati
> diversi da quello originale (la palla è volata oltre la staccionata;
> sono volata per non arrivare in ritardo).

Comment: Attenzione: anche nell'uso intransitivo “atterrare” ammette anche “avere” come ausiliare; cf. https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/atterrare

Comment: Grazie della precisazione, per la verità non lo avevo mai sentito dire, mi chiedo se ci sono forse delle differenze regionali nella lingua parlata.

Comment: È possibilissimo che ci siano differenze regionali nell'uso: a me (romano) non suona troppo strano. Potresti ritoccare la tua risposta? Così com'è adesso, dire “‘hai atterrato’ è sbagliato” non è corretto.

Comment: Certo, la cambio. Semmai scrivo che è corretto grammaticalmente, ma a me suona inconsueto. Io ho vissuto tutta la vita  tra Roma e Napoli, mai sentito 'hai atterrato'. Perciò ho pensato che forse è più usato al nord, ma non so.

Comment: Pare che non ci sia molto accordo: https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/atterrare-avere-o-essere_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/
dice che ‘avere’ è meno comune; https://www.sapere.it/sapere/dizionari/dizionari/Italiano/A/AT/atterrare.html dice che ‘avere’ è più comune. Se volete farvi venire il mal di testa, ecco un intervento dell'’Accademia della Crusca sull'uso degli ausiliari :https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/uno-sguardo-generale-sugli-ausiliari/13124.

che è sempre, in genere,  di opinioni non rigide.

Comment: Grazie mille, ha molto senso.

Comment: Figurati, grazie a te.Mi è venuto in mente un esempio in cui non mi sembra strano dire ‘hai atterrato’ invece di ‘sei atterrato’.  Se conoscessi un pilota di aereo gli chiederei ‘Dove hai atterrato?’ (è sottinteso che ha guidato l’aereo). 
Invece a un passeggero chiederei ‘Dove sei atterrato?, ‘hai atterrato’ mi suonerebbe bizzarro. 
Mi sembra che la differenza sia nella natura più attiva o più  passiva dell’azione.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few guidelines, which more or less routinely mentioned in textbooks on French, Italian, and German, all of which exhibit alternation between *to have* (*avoir/avere/haben*) and *to be* (*être/essere/sein*) as the auxhiliary verb for the past tense (*passé composé/passato prossimo/Perfekt*):

- The verbs using *to be* are usually the verbs of motion or state. Although this might include some rather abstract notions like *to be born* and *to die*, which one could interpret as *moving into/out of* life.
- Pronominal/reflexive verbs are always conjugated with *to be*
- Verbs conjugated with *to be* are always intransitive. In other words, a verb with a direct object is usually conjugated with *to have*, which is where the alternation usually comes from. Compare sentences *l'aereo è atterrato in orario* and *il pilota ha atterrato l'aereo* - in the second example the verb takes an object without preposition (which we call *direct object*), which mandates using *avere*.

**Remarks:**

- It must be noted however, that in French the number of (non-pronominal) verbs conjugated with *être* is very limited.
- As pointed in the comments, my example with *atterrare l'aereo* (*to land an airplane* / [*atterrir l'avion*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/atterrir+avion.html)) is impossible in Italian, where *atterrare* with a direct object is not used in literal sense. However, it can be used figuratively (*to bring/knock someone down*, *to ground somebody*), e.g.: *il pugile ha atterrato l'avversario con un solo pugno* (*The boxer knocked down the opponent with a single punch.*)
- See also [*Atterrare: avere o essere*](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/atterrare-avere-o-essere_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)

Comment: _il pilota ha atterrato l'aereo_ is not Italian. In its transitive use, _atterrare_ may be used on people (_atterrare qualcuno_ = to knock someone down or to humble him) and on some things in the sense of “to fell” or something. For aeroplanes, _atterrare_ is just intransitive. See https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/atterrare/

Comment: @DaG I suspected this much - I would be a lot more confident in French. I will add a note that the example is made up for illustrative purposes

Comment: One might perhaps substitute it with some other transitive use of _atterrare_, such as _il pugile ha atterrato l'avversario_.